# Unknown column "TableB.Date" in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

When I query a mysql database as follows I get an error as above in title.
No idea why, the problem is with the group by statement but i have tried several variations and nothing seems to work.

```
SELECT TableA.Name, DATE_FORMAT(TableB.Date, '%b %d %Y') AS "Date", COUNT(TableB.TableBID) 
  FROM TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.TableAID = TableB.TableAID
  WHERE TableA.Name = "john"
  GROUP BY DATE(TableB.Date)
  HAVING DATE_FORMAT(TableB.Date, '%b %d %Y') >= "Apr 12 2014"
  ORDER BY MAX(TableB.TableAID) ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do the comparison before the `group by` using a `where` condition.  And, you should do the comparison on dates and not strings:

```
SELECT a.Name, DATE_FORMAT(b.Date, '%b %d %Y') AS "Date", COUNT(b.TableBID) 
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.TableAID = b.TableAID
WHERE a.Name = 'john' AND
      b.date >= '2014-04-12'
GROUP BY DATE(b.Date)
ORDER BY MAX(b.TableAID) ASC;
```

The reason you want to do the filtering in the `where` is that it reduces the size of the data fed to the aggregation algorithm.  The reason you want to use dates instead of strings is because you don't want "March" to be after "April".  Note that I also changed the delimiters on the date constant to a single quote.

Comment: I accept this is the best solution however in this particular case I am required to keep the having clause. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not put `TableB.Date >= '2014-04-12'` in the WHERE clause?

The HAVING clause filters the output of the GROUP BY part of the query - whereas the WHERE clause filters the input to GROUP BY - and HAVING must reference one of the columns named in your query. Since you selected `TableB.Date AS "Date"`, you would need to refer to Date in the HAVING clause. But since you've used DATE_FORMAT to turn Date into a string you cannot compare it to another date and get the results you are expecting.

Also since DATE is a keyword in MySQL you save yourself some trouble by using something else as the column name. You can always wrap it in backticks to make sure MySQL knows it is a reference to a column name.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING can see alias,so

```
HAVING Date >= "Apr 12 2014"
```